# Networked Macs no longer show up in Finder windows

Tags: osx-yosemite

For years I've had my other macs on the network showing up on the left panel of Finder windows. Suddenly the other day, this stopped. I can still access the mac in question with a vnc:// link, or an afp:// link, so it appears the sharing permissions are still correct.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might just be too simple to be the answer, however...

When you hover over Shared does it say Show or Hide ?

[image]

[image]

If it says Show, click it.

Comment: Not too simple. Accepted! Must have accidentally clicked this thing. Didn't know about it.

Comment: I wish all issues could be as simple. Glad you got it :)